# Symfony3.4 Using two databases in one Application

Tags: database, entitymanager, symfony-3.4

I try to build an application with symfony 3.4 that access two different databases.

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

In this documentation i see that i had to configure my config.yml like this:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:

        default:
            driver: pdo_mysql
            host: '%database_host%'
            port: '%database_port%'
            dbname: '%database_name%'
            user: '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset: UTF8

        employeedb:
            driver:   pdo_mysql
            host:     '%database_host%'
            port:     '%database_port%'
            dbname:   '%database_name2%'
            user:     '%database_user%'
            password: '%database_password%'
            charset:  UTF8

  orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                AppBundle:  ~
        employeedb:
            connection: employeedb
            mappings:
                EmployeeBundle:  ~
```

I generate a seccond bundle for EmployeeBundle.
Now if i try to get values from the seccond database with a simple query it works fine:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('employeedb'); <br/>
$RAW_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM employee";
```

If i try with doctrine like this i get an error (ORMException):

```
$employees = $this->getDoctrine()
                  ->getRepository('EmployeeBundle:Employee')
                  ->findAll();
```

**Unknown Entity namespace alias 'EmployeeBundle'.**

What is wrong with my config? Should i add something in my entity_manager employeedb?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to give the name of the new entitymanager in the doctrine command:

```
     $results = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getManager('employeedb')
                    ->getRepository('EmployeeBundle:Employee')
                    ->findAll();
```